# How to click on doughnut Chart using selenium?

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium, automated-tests

I'm a trainee and trying to write a test using selenium in C# which clicks on a clickable chart and then this leads to another page. But the action doesn't work. I have also tried using JS.Executor to call a function in JavaScript, but that doesn't work either.
I have tried all possible ways i have found.
It would be nice if someone could help me.
Thank you very much in advance

Here is my chart:

[image: Screenshot of chart]

```
var obj = driver.FindElement(By.Id("someID"));
switch (chart)
{
    case string year when year.Contains("2020"):

        new Actions(driver).MoveToElement(obj).MoveByOffset(68, 120).Click().Build().Perform();
        //IJavaScriptExecutor exe = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
        //exe.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click()",obj);
        //exe.ExecuteScript("window.document.elementFromPoint(68, 120).click()");
        //exe.ExecuteScript("javascript:window.document.elementFromPoint(68, 120).click()");
        //new Actions(driver).MoveToElement(obj).MoveByOffset(68, 120).Click();
        //((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("javascript:clickAtChart();");
        //((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("clickAtChart();");
        //((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("clickAtChart(arguments[0],arguments[1]);","#circural_1","2020");
        break;

    case string year when year.Contains("älter"):
        new Actions(driver).MoveToElement(obj).MoveByOffset(68, 120).Click().Build().Perform();
        break;

    case string year when year.Contains("2019"):
        new Actions(driver).MoveToElement(obj).MoveByOffset(68, 120).Click().Build().Perform();
        break;
  
    case string year when year.Contains("2021"):
        new Actions(driver).MoveToElement(obj).MoveByOffset(68, 120).Click().Build().Perform();
        break;
}
```

here is my code and everything i have tried. none of them work properly

and this is the function i've tried to call.

```js
function clickAtChart(lable, locationID) {
    //var lable = "2020 (58.99 % | 164 )";
    //var locationID = "#circular_1";

    var interval = "";
    if (locationID === '#circular_1') {

        interval = 'YEAR_ONLY';
        var sqlOperator = '%3D';// %3D is a escaped for '='
        var Now = moment();
        var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
        var diff = 0;
        lable = lable.substring(0, 4);

        if (lable === "Älte" || lable === "Olde") {
            interval = 'YEAR';
            sqlOperator = "<";
            diff = -2;
        }
        else if (lable === (currentYear - 2).toString()) {
            diff = -2;
        }
        else if (lable === (currentYear - 1).toString()) {
            diff = -1;
        }
        else if (lable === (currentYear).toString()) {
            diff = 0;
        }
        else {

            var yearString = lable.substring(11, 15);
            var year = moment([yearString]);
            diff = year.diff(Now, 'days');
            interval = 'DAY';
            sqlOperator = '%3C'; //%3C is a escaped for '>'
        }


        window.location.href = DashboardUrlSettings.IndexForChart + '/?number=' + diff + '&interval=' + interval + '&sqlOperator=' + sqlOperator;

    }
    else if (locationID === '#circular_2' || locationID === '#circular_3') {
        var day = lable.substring(0, 4);

        var number = 0;
        var numberTo = 0;
        interval = 'DAY';
        var betweenSearch = false;
        var dateColumn = 'schadendatum_sch';

        if (day === "> 60") {
            number = -60;
            sqlOperator = '%3C'; //%3C is a escaped for '<'
        }
        else if (day === "30 -") {
            number = -30;
            numberTo = -60;
            betweenSearch = true;
        }
        else if (day === "< 30") {
            number = -30;
            sqlOperator = '%3E'; //%3C is a escaped for '>'
        }

        if (locationID === '#circular_3') {
            dateColumn = 'oasis_kommdokumente.sortdatum_d';
        }

        window.location.href = DashboardUrlSettings.IndexForChart + '/?number=' + number + '&numberTo=' + numberTo + '&interval=' + interval + '&betweenSearch=' + betweenSearch + '&sqlOperator=' + sqlOperator + '&dateColumn=' + dateColumn;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you receiving any error messages? If so, please post them as well. Also please add the rest of the code (you only pasted the part of the switch statement. It may be the only thing required but for the context it would be best to have a bit more code)

Comment: what's the html of the pie chart look like?

Comment: @beniutek 
no I don't get any error. In this scenario should be clicked only on the chart. There is nothing else than Switch statement

Comment: Note: I can click on chart myself and that works but automatic clicking does not work.
This means that the problem is not the chart but the click

Comment: @DMart  i only know that it is a nuget package and i have not found any html code, the chart is created in JS